# Definition Weierstrass $\zeta$-function unclear

Tags: elliptic-functions

The Weierstrass $\zeta$-function is defined as follows for a lattice $\Lambda$, where a lattice is a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ containing an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{C}$.

$$\zeta(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{\omega\in\Lambda\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}\right)$$

Doesn't $\sum_{\omega\in\Lambda\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{\omega}$ equal 0, because if $x \in \Lambda$ then $-x\in\Lambda$? I understand that the term appears when differentiating the logarithm of the Weierstrass $\sigma$-function, but why is it written anywhere if it could just as well be left out?

Comment: It's there to ensure absolute convergence

Comment: I heavily recommend to change the notation  $\;\zeta\;$ for the very well known and widely used $\;\wp\;$

Comment: This is not the same function; in fact $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\zeta(z) = -\wp(z)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1984530/532409 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2248789/532409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can'd do that rearrangement there because as written it is not absolutely convergent. On the other hand, with a small simplification,

$$\sum_{\omega\in\Lambda\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{z}{(z-\omega)\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}\right)$$

is absolutely convergent, because $\omega$ is quadratic is both denominators.

On a related note, an addition of some constant is often required to construct holomorphic/meromorphic functions with prescribed zeroes and poles and residues. See [Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) and [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) and their proofs on more along this line of thought.