# Weierstrass zeta, sigma function pseudo-peridocity identity

Tags: problem-solving, periodic-functions, integer-lattices, elliptic-functions

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

Let ${w_1,w_2} $ be a basis for $\Omega$ the period lattice.

Use $\zeta (z+ w_{i})=\zeta(z)+ n_i$ , $i=1,2$ ; $ m \in N$ for the Weierstrass zeta function to show that

$\sigma ( z + mw_i )=(-1)^m \exp^{(mn_i(z+mw_i/2))}\sigma(z)$

2. Relevant equations

To note that $\sigma(z)$ is an odd function.

$\zeta(z)=\frac{\sigma'(z)}{\sigma(z)}$

3. The attempt at a solution

I am pretty close but messing up with not getting $(-1)^m$

From $\zeta (z+ w_{i})=\zeta(z)+ n_i$ I get $\zeta (z+ mw_{i})=\zeta(z)+ mn_i$ .
$\frac{d}{dz} log \sigma(z+mw_i) = \frac{d}{dz} log \sigma(z) + mn_i$, and
$ \sigma(z+mw_i) =  \sigma(z)\exp{mn_i z} A $ , $A$ a constant of integration.

And now to determine $A$ I use the oddness of $\sigma(z)$ (odd as in odd function..) by setting $z=\frac{-mw_i}{2}$:
$\sigma(\frac{mw_i}{2})=\sigma(\frac{-mw_i}{2})A\exp^{-m^2n_iw_i/2}$
$\implies A= - \exp^{\frac{m^2n_iw_i}{2}}$
$ \sigma(z+mw_i) = -  \sigma(z)\exp{mn_i (z+mw_i/2)}  $ 
So I have a minus sign rather than $(-1)^m$ could someone please tell me what I have done wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try going inductively, rather than trying to calculate the whole thing all in one go.

Comment: Instead of $\sigma$, you meant $\wp$ the Weierstrass elliptic function ?

Comment: No, it is $\sigma$ which has no poles, only zeros only on the period lattice. The $\wp$ has double poles there.

Answer (score 1):

You made a simple mistake. In your step when you set $z=-mw_i/2$ you neglected to note that $\sigma(z)$ has zeros at all integer multiples of $w_i$, and so when you divided out by $\sigma(\frac{mw_i}{2})$ and $m$ is even then you are dividing by zero. When $m$ is odd, you just get $-1$ which is $(-1)^m$ when $m$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I have $\frac{\sigma(mw_i/2)}{\sigma(-mw_i/2)}\exp^{+..}=A$; I see what you are saying, so that $m=1$ I get $-1$. And if $m$ is even, I am dividing by zero- so how do I deal with this?this is just disallowed so we must set $m$ to odd. But if this is the case then surely you would just use $-1$ ? I also can't see how you get $(-1)^m$ from this? many thanks

Comment: A comment from Chappers gave a good suggestion. If you know the formula for all m odd, then you just have to add a period to cover all m even because you can use the formula for m=1. That is, m = 2k = (2k-1) + 1, so apply the formula for (2k-1) and 1 in succession. There are other ways.

Comment: Hi I have done a proof by induction ( didn't take two years I had years out of my study hahaah ) which seems to work. Is this still valid , it seems to avoid the m even or odd concern re . dividing by zero. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have your proof to examine, but it probably is valid. Hindsight is 20/20.